# How to check if the choices selected by the candidate are correct in a Quiz Application in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am making a Quiz application in Django and I wanted to know how I can get the number of questions answered correctly by the user?

models.py

```html
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=15000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=15000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
class CorrectChoice(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = "")
    correct_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.correct_choice
```

template

```html
<form action = '/quiz/next/' method = 'post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2>{{ question }}</h2>
            {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'choice' id = 'choice' value = '{{ choice.choice_text }}'>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ choice.choice_text }}<br>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            <button class = 'btn btn-primary' type = 'submit' style = 'width: 100px'>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

views.py

```html
def next_ques(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
     choices = []
     choice = request.POST['choice']
     choices.append(choice)
     choices = set(choices)
     answers = set(CorrectChoice.objects.all())
     total = len(choices.intersection(answers))
     question = e.next_question()
     if question == False :
        return HttpResponse(str(total))
     else :
      context = {
         'question':question
      }
      return render(request, 'quiz.html', context)
    else :
        return('Invalid')
```

Whenever I run this code, I get total as 0

Comment: Can you post sample code of your models and the relationship between them?

Comment: Hi! I have edited my question

Comment: You are not executing the queryset in your for loop. Try `for choice in question.choice_set.all()`

Comment: @JosephM I get a template syntax error when I do that, error : Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'question.choice_set.all()'

Answer (score 0):

I think ...

`choices` is a set of numbers which are the ids of individual `Choice` model records.

`answers` is a set of `Choice` model records.

They will not intersect.